# Average interest rate

Tags: interest-rates, mean

Earlier I asked a question about [average FX rate](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/48772/currency-exchange-rate). I'm building simple linear model and need to use monthly data. I have a yearly interest rate that changes daily. How to aggregate it over the month, can I compute simple arithmetic average?

Comment: Like the other question, it completely depends on the context whether you want EOM, BOM, arithmetic average, or geometric average. It all depends on what you're using the rates for (meaning are you correlating it with other data that is EOM, BOM, etc,), what frequency of compounding you need, how the rates were derived, and what day count conventions are used. There's not a blanket answer that covers all cases.